# How to set jquery ajax headers authorization based on url?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, wordpress

I have a wordpress website that has woocommerce ajax requests on its Order Page. The website has a staging domain and a live domain.

```
$(function(){
   var root_url = 'https://'+window.location.hostname;
   console.log(root_url);
});
```

Ajax Request sample for staging:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url: https://staging-mywebsite.net/wp-json/wc/v2/products?category=504,
  cache: false,
  beforeSend: function(jqXHR, settings) {
  },
  headers: {"Authorization": "Basic " + btoa("ck_123" + ":" + "cs_123") // staging},
  success: function(data) {
  }
});
```

Ajax Request sample for Live site:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url: https://livewebsite.com/wp-json/wc/v2/products?category=504,
  cache: false,
  beforeSend: function(jqXHR, settings) {
  },
  headers: {"Authorization": "Basic " + btoa("ck_456" + ":" + "cs_456") // staging},
  success: function(data) {
  }
});
```

The live and staging website has **different** username and password on the `headers` property.

Do you know how can I set a condition or a global variable for the `headers` property depending on the domain?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using the document.domain property? I'm thinking something like this:

```
var headers = {"Authorization": "Basic " + btoa("ck_456" + ":" + "cs_456")} // Assume live site
if( document.domain === "staging-mywebsite.net" ){
  headers = {"Authorization": "Basic " + btoa("ck_123" + ":" + "cs_123")} // Use staging instead
}
```

And then inside your AJAX request you use the variable instead.

```
...
headers: headers,
...
```

Comment: Worked like charm. Thank you